# Inserting Favicon into html form

Tags: html, css

How do insert a favicon into my search form?

I understand now how to add a favicon to my title bar of my website, but I don't quite understand how to add a favicon to a html form (search bar)

I have tried using css and adding it as a background with the following properties no-repeat scroll 7px 7px;
padding-left:30px;

but that didnt do anything.

Please help

Comment: FYI It doesn't work in chrome...

Comment: Show your CSS!  A favicon is not the same thing as a css background image.  Two totally different things.  favicons are only for the browser title bara/favorites.  You cannot add a favicon to individual elements on the page - you need to use CSS backgrounds for that.

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` section of your site add this

`<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/pathToImage/image.png"/>`

make sure your favicon is 16x16px and is in .ico format.

and remember, chrome does not dysplay it.

Comment: Chrome does display it, just not in the address bar, but on the tab itself.

Comment: @HaukurHaf yeah no kidding! OP asked for "search bar" and I am assuming he meant "address bar", is that a fair assumption?

Comment: Well, he did also say "html form", so I'm not sure it is :-).  Anyhow, the OP's question is bad.